# Trigger a Custom Event in ABAP ZPROGRAM

Tags: email, abap

I am developing in ABAP.
I have a requirement to trigger a custom event in an ABAP Z-program.
Can anyone pls tell me how can I call a custom event in  a Z-program  to send an email.
(please note: It is not workflow, I need to complete this task in the Z-program).

Comment: Please try to describe the requirements and the environment in more detail. In its current state, the question does not make clear what you want to do and especially what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am required to Generate an email of the report, that I have designed using Z-Program when user clicks the button Email report.

Comment: @H.K Nope, still the same...

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little vague, so in general if you talk about a button to press and a following action that is to be triggered you may need to:

- define a button for the Application Toolbar in GUI-Status with a custom function code that is used when the button is clicked
- add a gloabl general attribute with "type of screen element" = OK to the dynpro screen's element list
- check this global attribute in the PAI module for the custom function code value and then perform/call your sendEmail function

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom event within transaction SM62. At your program, you call the function module BP_EVENT_RAISE, to raise your custom event. "eventid" is the name of the event you created previously at SM62.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code example to send an email in ABAP z-program code, via calling function module [SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/so_new_document_send_api1.html) (SAPoffice: Send new document):

```
* Data Declarations
DATA: LT_MAILSUBJECT     TYPE SODOCCHGI1.
DATA: LT_MAILRECIPIENTS  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SOMLREC90 WITH HEADER LINE.
DATA: LT_MAILTXT         TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SOLI      WITH HEADER LINE.
* Recipients
LT_MAILRECIPIENTS-REC_TYPE  = 'U'.
LT_MAILRECIPIENTS-RECEIVER = 'sheetal@gmail.com'.
APPEND LT_MAILRECIPIENTS .
CLEAR LT_MAILRECIPIENTS .
* Subject.
LT_MAILSUBJECT-OBJ_NAME = 'TEST'.
LT_MAILSUBJECT-OBJ_LANGU = SY-LANGU.
LT_MAILSUBJECT-OBJ_DESCR = 'Mail Subject'.
* Mail Contents
LT_MAILTXT = 'This is a test mail'.
APPEND LT_MAILTXT. CLEAR LT_MAILTXT.
* Send Mail
CALL FUNCTION 'SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1'
  EXPORTING
    DOCUMENT_DATA              = LT_MAILSUBJECT
  TABLES
    OBJECT_CONTENT             = LT_MAILTXT
    RECEIVERS                  = LT_MAILRECIPIENTS
  EXCEPTIONS
    TOO_MANY_RECEIVERS         = 1
    DOCUMENT_NOT_SENT          = 2
    DOCUMENT_TYPE_NOT_EXIST    = 3
    OPERATION_NO_AUTHORIZATION = 4
    PARAMETER_ERROR            = 5
    X_ERROR                    = 6
    ENQUEUE_ERROR              = 7
    OTHERS                     = 8.
IF SY-SUBRC EQ 0.
  COMMIT WORK.
*   Push mail out from SAP outbox
  SUBMIT RSCONN01 WITH MODE = 'INT' AND RETURN.
ENDIF.
```